# Netbeans Macro: Jump to Next Bracket "}" From Wherever

Tags: netbeans, macros, ide, netbeans-7

I have recently adopted Netbeans and I would like to create a macro that immediately jumps the caret to the next "}" bracket from **wherever** in the document.

`CTRL + [` does not work because this requires that you are at "{" or "}".

Example:

```
if ($logic) {

    // Do some stuff
    |    <------------------- Caret is here.
}
```

As soon as the macro is run, the caret is moved down to "}" and to the right of the curly bracket:

```
if ($logic) {

    // Do some stuff

}| <-------------- caret is here now
```

I know this is possible becausse I had it working yesterday but for some reason the macro is not registering:

## Current Macro

`caret-end-word find-next "}"`

Instead of finding the next curly bracket and moving the caret accordingly, Netbeans is simply writing in "}".

## Question

Any help with the macro would be greatly appreciated! Better yet - if someone could help me understand the macro encoding... how does one distinguish from outputting "}" versus actually just finding "}"? Or is the macro editor too primitive?

Comment: I really like Netbeans, and this feature is so useful, but the lack of any real macro documentation usage is annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this information is still applicable to Netbeans 7, but [this bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=146810) was filed in 2008. Originally, the user reported being unable to pass parameters to the `find-next` macro. The dev team responded that it was a new feature request, not a bug. This makes be believe that the intended behavior of `find-next` is equivalent to hitting F3; you have to already have typed in a search string (which makes it pretty useless as a macro). As far as I can tell, the feature still hasn't been developed, so you might be out of luck.

Comment: That is correct! As long as "}" in the find next input the macro will work perfectly.